# repeat value in a php array

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, do-while

I want to do a schedule pattern that repeat the value every 4 days...
Below the php script is looping the date from 1-Sept til 30-Sept.I want to repeat the value for every 4 days...
For example, my value is (A,B,C,D) and I want to repeat it every 4day...thats mean

```
1/9 = A 
2/9 = B 
3/9 = C 
4/9 = D 
5/9 = A 
6/9 = B 
7/9 = C 
8/9 = D
```

...... til 30/9 then stop...

```
<?php  
// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Start date
$start_date = '2015-09-01';
// End date
$end_date = '2015-09-30';

$value = "A";

while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
echo "$start_date <br>";
$start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));

}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
$values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

// Start date
$start_date = '2015-09-01';
// End date
$end_date = '2015-09-30';

$current_date = $start_date;
$index = 0;
while (strtotime($current_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $i = $index % count($values);
    echo "$current_date: $values[$i]\n";
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current_date)));
    $index++;
}
```

`%` is a [modulus operator](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), which returns remainder of a division. `$a % $b` returns remainder of `$a` divided by `$b`. So for example `6 % 4` is 2, `7 % 4` is is 3 and so on.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped you. You can also up-vote my answer as a reward ;)

Comment: `count($values)` can be pulled out of the loop.

Comment: You can avoid three `strtotime` date string to UNIX time conversions per iteration.

Comment: @mvw Put it as a comment of the question, please. It's his code, not mine. I didn't change his code so he can easily recognize, what's solution to his question. But I agree with your comments.

Answer (score 1):

And another version:

```
<?php  
// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Start date
$start_date = strtotime('2015-09-01');
// End date
$end_date = strtotime('2015-09-30');

$value = "A";

for ($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date; 
     $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date)) {
  $date_str = date("Y-m-d", $date);
  echo "$date_str: $value<br>\n";
  $value++;
  if ($value > "D") {
    $value = "A";
  }
}
?>
```

Note: While the variables have date suffixes, they contain UNIX time values, and not some kind of date object.

Comment: This will work only in this specific case, but not for example for these values: `$values = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']`.

Comment: It would also work for 42,43,44,45 and all types that are ordered, have addition defined, and when the values succeed each other.

Comment: Yep, but that's what I'm talking about - it will work for specific input values only, it's not general algorithm. So it would be good to make a note about that in your answer. I'm not saying it's bad, I'm saying that it will work just for a very specific cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// Start date
$start_date = '2015-09-01';
// End date
$end_date   = '2015-09-30';

$value = array(
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D"
);
$i     = 0;
while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    echo "$start_date = " . $value[$i] . " <br>";
    if ($i == count($value) - 1) {
        $i = 0;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
    $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($start_date)));

}
?>
```